# how to write a public class MyList<E>?

Tags: java, generics

so let's say i want to write somthing like an ArrayList
just not a list but an ArrayGrid (2 dimensional versioon)

I already figured out that ArrayList uses an Object[]
to store data.

so i made an

```
private Object[][] grid;
```

but my getData method throws a ClassCastException:

```
public E[][] getData(){
    return (E[][]) grid;
}
```

The above method and this one:

```
public E get(int x, int y){
    return (E) grid[x][y];
}
```

both are giving me a warning: "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to E"

I can imagine why, but i can't seen to find a solution. So how does ArrayList do that?

Comment: if you look at the source of `ArrayList`, it suppresses the warning

Comment: The important thing here is the ClassCastException, not that warning. Look at my answer for more details (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882338/how-to-write-a-public-class-myliste/22883431#22883431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/EdwardLee03/openjdk-7/blob/master/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java) the ArrayList.java file if it could help.

**EDIT :** this is the portion you are looking for :

```
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}


/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 *
 * @param  index index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);


    return elementData(index);
}
```

**EDIT :correcion**
But if you use generic type you can do like this instead of using object:

```
    private E[][] grid; //seems to be impossible
```

Comment: yeah.. they are using  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on elementData which is used by get()

Comment: No i can't because it says "Cannot create a generic array of E"